# Select where has many childs has two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relation

I have 2 tables (in MYSQL):

cards:

- id
- created_at
- updated_at

card_values:

- card_id
- field_id
- value
- created_at
- updated_at

The table cards has many card_values. How can I select:

A **card** that "has" a **card_value** where field_id = 2 **AND**

the **SAME** card "has" an other **card_value** where field_id = 3

[Image: Select card where this conditions are true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/docAW.png)

Comment: This works, but seens wrong:
SELECT * FROM cards
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT * FROM card_values WHERE card_values.card_uuid = cards.uuid AND card_values.field_id = 2 AND JSON_EXTRACT(card_values.value, '$.value') in (111, '111')
)
AND EXISTS (
 SELECT * FROM card_values WHERE card_values.card_uuid = cards.uuid AND card_values.field_id = 21 AND JSON_EXTRACT(card_values.value, '$.value') in ('Cacaca')
)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM cards c JOIN card_values cv ON cv.card_id = c.id WHERE cv.field_value = 2 OR cv.field_value = 3` .. should do the thing.